# gibberish instead of a file urllib.request

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to send a request with urllib.request
to get a CSV file, but instead the file I'm getting an HTML with gibberish in it.
here is my code:

```
import urllib.request

url = ('https://data.gov.il/dataset/covid-19/resource/a2b2fceb-3334-44eb-b7b5-9327a573ea2c/'
       'download/corona_deceased_ver_0028.csv')

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
     csv = url.read()
     print(csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get correct response, you need to set `User-Agent` HTTP header and `rbzid` cookie (maybe you have to copy it from your browser):

```
import requests


url = 'https://data.gov.il/dataset/covid-19/resource/a2b2fceb-3334-44eb-b7b5-9327a573ea2c/download/corona_deceased_ver_0028.csv'
cookies = {
    'rbzid': 'PtkzXD64cWBOiLLfQ9GPun/ZTK7c6Qn+AZsK+og/lNnrjGl0uXKvDfHW4xvSLZnEyZEN6D4FuXEHq/pcN71VYGOkyHNtBb89VwjskA6LumbcIThp0tn89XEbVtlwuu8h918KOzuIx+3ad5BGETL0b3Ak1REM7nItp1tcCD63Qat1f8nVaAlsDLfrOUf/Lu1XAz/eArm8WboiU0I6ccS0tu7vHebosdk4luT2KVL+IYNL6N6nCf9himXu4BDOn74Z',
}
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

print(requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Prints:

```
gender,age_group,Ventilated,Time_between_positive_and_hospitalization,Length_of_hospitalization,Time_between_positive_and_death
זכר,75-84,0,0,4.0,4
נקבה,<65,1,0,2.0,2
נקבה,85+,0,0,4.0,4
נקבה,85+,0,2.0,6.0,8
נקבה,75-84,1,0,8.0,8
זכר,75-84,1,-1.0,14.0,8

...and so on.
```